# Laravel update query value pass error

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am trying to update my table using this laravel db query

```
public function addRetailer($Id)
    {
        $getId = Input::get($Id);

        $updateData = array(
                            'IsActive' => 1
                            );

        $updateRetailer = DB::table('retailer')->where('ID',$getId)->update($updateData);

        if($updateRetailer)
        {
            return redirect('/Retailers_List');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/Blocked_Retailers');
        }
    }
```

But the $getId has the value..but when the query is executed it fails, instead if I write it statically like

```
public function addRetailer($Id)
    {
        $getId = Input::get($Id);

        $updateData = array(
                            'IsActive' => 1
                            );

        $updateRetailer = DB::table('retailer')->where('ID','1')->update($updateData);

        if($updateRetailer)
        {
            return redirect('/Retailers_List');
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/Blocked_Retailers');
        }
    }
```

it works perfectly fine.  Whats the error. And moreover , The routes has the get method. the Id is perfectly passes on the URl, I can also get it. But I dont know where I am going wrong?

Any help?

Comment: Here you don't need to write `$getid = Input::get($id)`. You can directly use `$id` in your `where` clause.

Comment: I dit it...but still it causes me the same error.

Comment: Try to check what you are getting in `$id` using `dd($id)`

Comment: What error you  were getting over here.

Comment: try to use **Input::get($Id)** in your  query directly

Comment: @Ali I am getting the Id here...which is 1

Comment: @YasinPatel I have already used it... and I am getting the data too...

Comment: @Uchiha If I pass the variable, it does not update the databse... But if I pass the value statically, within the quote...as the second code I have written, It works fine...

Comment: What is the value of `$id`? @JijoNair. Simply use `$id` instead of `1` and check what happens over there.

Comment: It returns me nothing...no update..nothing...it just throw me error

Comment: just edit your question and show the error message what you are facing.

Comment: Update your question with that error. @JijoNair

Comment: Update your question with the error

Answer (score 0):

Try this function instead

```
public function addRetailer($Id)
{    
    $updateData = array(
       'IsActive' => 1
    );

    $updateRetailer = DB::table('retailer')->where('ID',$Id)->update($updateData);

    if($updateRetailer)
    {
        return redirect('/Retailers_List');
    }

    return redirect('/Blocked_Retailers');
}
```

Comment: didn worked out......and yes, I forgot to mention that, I am using UUID code..hence the Id that I receive is Alphanumeric UUID code....